# Passing more than one value into a button in the server side Datatable Jquery using MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to pass the value of MessageId and MobileNumber as argument into Delete button. At the moment only the value of MessageId is showing when I run the javascript code below (i don't know how to add the value of MobileNumber). Any help please

```
 var schedulemessageListVM;
    $(function () {
        schedulemessageListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {
                dt = $('#schedulemessage-data-table').DataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/MessageReport/LoadData2",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },

                    "columns": [
                     {

                        "targets": [0],
                            "data": "MessageId",  "autoWidth": true,
                            "render": function (data, type, full)
                            {
                             // Pass the value of MessageId and  MobileNumber into the button
                                var a = '@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "MessageReport", new { id = "MessageId" }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger" })'.replace("MessageId", data);

                                return a;                                    
                            },
                        },
                        { "title": "Message Id", "data": "MessageId", "name": "MessageId", "autoWidth": true }
                        { "title": "Mobile Number", "data": "MobileNumber", "name": "MobileNumber", "autoWidth": true }
                   ]
                });
            }                 
        } 
        // initialize the datatables 
        schedulemessageListVM.init();

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution of the problem with help of my colleague. Posting to help people with the same issue in the future

```
     "render": function (data,  type, full)
       {
           {
              return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/MessageReport/Delete?MessageId='+full.MessageId+'&MobileNumber='+full.MobileNumber+'">Delete </a>';
           }

      }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach below which will not need any complicated data passing before the button is clicked:

First create a row for the button and add a `DeleteBtn` class to use it as selector later. I does not need any more information on it.

```
"columns":[{
            "data": "Delete",
            "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-danger DeleteBtn">Delete</button>',
            "title": "Delete"
        }, ...
```

Now define an event to be executed when button is clicked and pass the `data` object to function:

```
    $("#myTable").on("click", ".DeleteBtn", function () {
 myDeleteFunction($("#myTable").DataTable().row($(this).parents("tr")).data()) });
```

Now the passed data contains all the information you might need and can be used like:

```
    fucntion myDeleteFunction(data){
 alert(data.MessageId);
 alert(data.MobileNumber);
 }
```

Or any other data needed from the row.

---

If you are not familiar with the  `$("#myTable").DataTable().row($(this).parents("tr")).data())` concept:

`$("#myTable").DataTable()` defines that method related to DataTables will be used.

`.row()` is used to select a row of the table and needs a selector.

`this.parents("tr")` Selects the row of the table that includes the clicked delete button.

`.data()` will return data of the selected row as an object.