# JavaScript + Jquery DataTable - pass data to defaultContent json column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have a dynamic jQuery data table. For the final column, I have the option of deleting rows. In order for this to execute, I need to pass the itemId value to the function specified within the button onClick attribute.

This is how I have currently done it but no luck:

```
defaultContent: "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='StockSearchManagment.DeleteStock(" + data.itemId + ")'>Delete</button>"
```

This is my full JavaScript function:

```
 GetInfo: function (tble) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetList',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            tble.DataTable().destroy();
            tble.DataTable({
                data: data.html
                ,
                "columns": [
                    { data: "itemId" },
                    { data: "name" },
                    { data: "description" },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='StockSearchManagment.DeleteStock(" + data.ItemId + ")'>Delete</button>"
                    }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refered to this stack overflow question:
[Passing more than one value into a button in the server side Datatable Jquery using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966375/passing-more-than-one-value-into-a-button-in-the-server-side-datatable-jquery-us)

It's now working with render instead of defaultContext:

```
"render": function (data, type, full) {

 return '<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="StockSearchManagment.DeleteStock(' + full.itemId + ')">Delete</button>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can tag the button you generate with a "data" tag and read that from the onlick event.

the tag would look like:

<button ... data-id="">

the onlick event would do this: var itemid =  $(this).attr('data-id').val();

and then you'd have the value to use.

Comment: He can also get data like: `$(this).data('id')`